# FileOutputStream doesn't show FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, io, filenotfoundexception

for `FileOutputStream`, it will *throw* a `FileNotFoundException` if the file doesn't exist, but it will *create* it if it can.

**I dont have a `Sample.txt` in my project root**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            FileOutputStream s=  new FileOutputStream("Sample.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is:

- I cannot see the Output of the **"File Not Found"** from the `Terminal`. How did it happen?

Thank you

Comment: Have you debugged to see if it reaches the line with System.out.println("File not Found");?

Comment: as per javadocs *FileNotFoundException - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason*

Comment: You don't write anything to the file, I'm not certain an exception is actually possible here.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I didn't put anything into, but the constructor `public FileOutputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException ` it would throw a exception

Comment: @ScaryWombat you are correct, it was my fault to understand it in plain words. you have my vote

Comment: @Ruizhi I get that, but it's an abstract operation until you try to write... e.g. you can open a write-protected filesystem path for writing (on most operating systems) without any problem - until you actually try to write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Sample.txt as a File first and check if it exists with .canWrite()

You still have to put a try/catch around FileOutputStream, but it should never go in the catch block.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("Sample.txt");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        }
        else {
            try {
                FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`canWrite()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite())

Comment: thank you, but, the `else` part of your code means that *if the file is there, then use the FileOutputStream to create a stream for that file*, but, even if the file does't exist at all, the `FileOutputStream` still can create that file for you. I think the problem is, if the `f` is a folder, it is not possible to write into it.